# parseInt convertion gives 1 for 1,000

Tags: javascript

parseInt convertion 1,000.00 gives 1 but i want 1000 , what is the problem?

```
<html>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(parseInt("1,000.00")) ;  // always gives output 1
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: maybe the comma, which is not part of a number?

Comment: Remove the comma `if possible` because its not part of a numeric value.

Comment: here i am converting sring to int

Comment: I think you need to parseFloat(). Im not sure how JS is interpreted but I don't think 1,000.00 is interpreted as an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
parseInt("1,000.00".replace(/\,/g,''), 10)
```

If you want to preserve the decimal then,

```
parseFloat("1,000.00".replace(/\,/g,''), 10)
```

Comment: A person with your rep should know that this a very basic question and **should be** marked as duplicate instead of answering

Comment: Thank you sir. Next time be polite on your comment and it's a request.

Comment: I'm sorry for being rude but you have been here more than me. You should lead by example. Answering a duplicate is not a good practice.

Comment: @VJAI ok, this works. But what if I'm trying to do this in a loop? (not knowing which number is the one with ",")

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma first and execute the `parseInt`. Try this:

```
parseInt("1,000.00".replace(",",""));
```

Comment: what about `parseInt("1000,00")`?

Comment: Your replace will only change one ",". You should use `parseInt("1,000.00".replace(/,/g, "")) ;`

Comment: what it means  replace(/,/g, "") ?

Comment: @ShaikMatheen `//` is used to define a `regex`. `g` is a flag that will check string recursively. so `(/,/g, "")` will recursively look for `,` and replace it with `""`

Comment: Ah yes. I was focused on the given number on the post. But the best thing to do would be the regex which was commented by @Shubham

Comment: Also @prtdomingo, please do not answer question that are very basic. There is a high possibility that they have already been answered. You should search such post and share them as comment until you have permission to close a question. Post that please mark it duplicate

Comment: Sure. Would do it next time. Thanks!